# Sign in on Cloud Tools plugin for Android Studio not working

Tags: android, google-app-engine, ubuntu, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

After updating my Android Studio to its latest version, I created a simple application using Google Endpoints (thus it requires access to Google Cloud services).

However, when I tried to sign up my user on AS, I got the following error:

```
Argument for @NotNull parameter 'userEmail' of 
    com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser
    must not be null.
```

I removed the files at `~/.AndroidStudio*`, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 64-bits, and I totally forgot that uninstalling an application does not remove the configurations files created by Android Studio and X-Window.

So before launching your updated AS, remove the following directories:

```
~/.AndroidStudio*
~/.java/.userPrefs
```